# PHPExcel: Some Lines are not exporting in my .xls file while importing but shown when i echo the output?

Tags: php, mongodb, phpexcel

I am using **PHPExcel** with **mysql and MongoDB** to **export data in Excel .XLS** file but only in 1 Column some Lines are not showing and some are showing in same Columns **while exporting** although all are shown when i use **$print_()** to check output in **browser**

Here is my **PHP Code** -

```
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(); 
$sheet->setCellValue('M1', 'Headline');

 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('M')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('M')->getFont()->setUnderline(true);

            if ($result['type'] == "WEB") {

                $sheet->setCellValue('M' . ($results + 2), $result['headline']);
                $sheet->getCell('M' . ($results + 2))->getHyperlink()->setUrl($result['url']);
                $sheet->getCell('M' . ($results + 2))->getHyperlink()->setTooltip('Navigate to website');

}
```

and this is **my output**

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5r8F.png)

Comment: I really suggest you to change with new PHPSpreedsheet. That have much implemantion for do all operation you want.  [LINK](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: As my whole code and server is on php version 5 i don't think so PHPSpreadsheer is going to work

Comment: it's time to upgrade :)

Comment: you try my code?

Answer (score 1):

I post here an example without link (you can edit my code):

```
$objPHPExcel    =   new PHPExcel();
$result         =   $db->query("SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE") or die(mysql_error());

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('M1', 'Headline');


$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("M1")->getFont()->setBold(true);

 $rowCount   =   2;
while($row  =   $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('M'.$rowCount, mb_strtoupper($row['headline'],'UTF-8'));


    $rowCount++;
}


$objWriter  =   new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);


header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); //mime type
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="you-file-name.xlsx"'); //tell browser what's the file name
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');  
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```